# How to get strings with the right text from a website GET request, avoiding special HTML codes?

Tags: java, character-encoding, httpurlconnection

I'm getting a spanish website code throught an HttpConnection object, using a GET request. When I print the output throught the console (the website code), the spanish characters are not there.  Instead, there are some "weird" characters.

It's supposed that the website encoding is at "UTF-8" (), but I don't know how is it dealing with the spanish characters (á, ñ, etc.)

I tried a lot of things, like define the charset property in UTF-8, in the setRequestProperty method, building the string from a char array, building the string from a byte array using the UTF-8 specific encoding, because I read somewhere that the Java String class build the strings at UTF-16 by default, and, no. It still giving me all those strange characters.

I also tried the same things using the ISO-8859-1 encoding, with the same bad result, and also without any encode specification.

Ok, I know that those characters do follow a pattern, and I could made a class to "translate" them, but I'm pretty sure that there are much better options before that one.

```
String myMethod() {

    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
    con.setUseCaches(false);
    con.setDoInput(true);
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

    return reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

}
```

Thats one example of what happens.

The sentence that is written in the website (and I want to get):

"Equipo de protección otoño de toda la estaciòn"

The sentence I actually get from my output:

```
"Equipo de protecci&oacute;n oto&ntilde;o de toda la estaci&ograve;n"
```

Comment: It's about layers. HTTP knows nothing of HTML. HTML document's character encoding is independent of the actual content. HTML can use named or numeric character entity references. In the end, all characters are Unicode. Your code and/or libraries you use have to deal with each of the layers.

Comment: Thank you @TomBlodget. Now I understand the base matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the StringEscapeUtils from Apache Commons (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6).

```
String dirty = "Equipo de protecci&oacute;n oto&ntilde;o de toda la estaci&ograve;n";
String clean = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(dirty);
```

Output: Equipo de protección otoño de toda la estaciòn

Hope this helps. Good luck. Post a comment if you have any follow-up queries.

Comment: Hey, thanks, but I have some trouble with this.
I just downloaded and added the that library. I have adjusted my code well (as you have shown) but I got the following exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils
[...]

I researched a bit about that kind of exceptions, but I've found that they can be caused by a lot of reasons. So, if you can help me with this, I'll be very greatful.

Comment: Create a maven project, add the dependency from the link.

Comment: I was actually working on "native" Java, so it seems I have just a couple of options:
1) Migrating the project to Maven
2) Write my own library to deal with that issue
Ok, thanks, I'm thinking about it.

Comment: You can simply extract the code for the method you want from the library and add it to your project.

Comment: I finally used Maven. It seems a great idea. Thank you so much.